# Android Google Oauth issue

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm trying out an Android-Google_web_app integrated authentication presented here: http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html

Basically the Android app should get an OAuth token that is linked to my existing web app client_id. My sample app works fine when I get the token from a google api for instance: "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile".

When I change the scope to my web app client id: "audience:server:client_id:1044492925447-9vr9sqjsb7kqs51ks89jfcufeq0rfvu6.apps.googleusercontent.com"

The GoogleAuthUtil.getToken throws a GoogleAuthException with a blank message so I don´t know what's going on.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: Have you verified that 1) you can get an OAuth2 token for both client IDs (server and android client app, try them in separate flows) and 2) both clients are registered in the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the cause of the problem.

There was a mismatch of the **Package name** between the Android app and the "Client ID for installed applications" on the Goolgle API console.

I had created a sample app for testing purposes and thought that the package name would be irrelevant.